# How to return a view result without layout from a ServiceStack service?

Tags: c#, razor, servicestack

I have a `ServiceStack`.`Service` implementation that defines a method that must return `HTML` markup, but a fragment only. I tried to just set the `View` property of the an `HttpResult` object without specifying a layout in the `Razor` view nor do I set the `Template` property of the result - and I expected to get the view markup only, which is not the case.

The view is derived from `ViewPage`. The service function looks like that...

```
public class SampleService : Service
{
    public IHttpResult Get(GetSampleRequest request)
    {
        return new HttpResult
        {
            View = "SampleView"
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is that `ServiceStack` tries to find a default layout (which exists) and uses that. How can I prevent that? In ASP.NET MVC I would usually just return the result from the `Partial` extension method; does something similiar exist in `ServiceStack`?

Comment: In your view that you're returning, have you tried defining the `Layout = ""`? e.g. `@{ Layout = ""; }`

Comment: @GeoffJames Oh my... it was really that simple (-;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to define a `Layout` in your Razor View as empty.

However, setting it to `null` just defaults to using the `_Layout.cshtml` page (or whatever's defined as your default).

In your Razor View, set the `Layout` to `""`, like so:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
 }
```

You could also set `Layout = string.Empty`. Both have the same desired effect.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also set a layout that contains nothing or just a comment to indicate it was deliberate `"_LayoutEmpty.cshtml"`. Kind of a design choice vs an empty string name.

Answer (score 1):

In the Razor View, add

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

Comment: AFAIK, setting the `Layout` to `null`, just defines that there is no layout specified, and defaults to the `_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: We use this statement in MVC if we want to render dialog content without menus etc. and this seems to work.

Comment: @GeoffJames Exactly

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider - I agree with you, in an out-the-box MVC project I find this is the case. But from what I can tell, in ServiceStack, when a `Layout` is `null`, the default layout page is used. i.e. setting it to `null` in the view, or not defining it at all